# How to make Blender render in real-time, as fast a computer game?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I understand from this answer (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136757/how-do-modern-game-engines-achieve-real-time-rendering-vs-blenders-slow-rende#answer-136776) that

- computer games (and libraries like three.js and babylon.js) simply project objects onto the camera, and can thus render instantly
- whereas Blender does raytracing, which takes minutes per frame.

**Is there any setting I can change to make Blender use the projection mode of rendering rather than raytracing?**  I've already done all the rendering performance tricks and I'm still orders of magnitude away from real time.

The answer referenced above says Blender Internal renderer is much faster than Cycles, but Internal is being removed from Blender 2.8 onwards, so that's not a solution.

---

If there is no Blender solution, then **would using Blender to make models and Unity to make animations be be the best plan?**  I haven't used Unity but I assume it can do the speedy rendering thing.

Comment: Have you looked into 2.8ths eevee engine? Or how about the blender game engine?

Comment: Do you want to make a game or a movie?

Comment: Thanks @kanukit. Looks like 2.8 solves my problem with real time rendering. I'll download the alpha and take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Blender 2.80 Beta Version to get a new render engine called Eevee. The engine is lighter in performance consumption and can do real  time rendering even more realistically than the traditional Blender Render engine. Note: Before you open the old Blender file in 2.80 Beta, then keep a backup copy. Because once you open or create a project in Blender 2.80 Beta then you can't open it again in older versions. The physics engine is not yet completed. So, don't use the physics engine in Blender 2.80 Beta. If there is a bug or a problem in a feature of Blender 2.80 Beta,  then download the next day's version to get a better working version of Blender 2.80 Beta.